# Handling line breaks from XML to HTML

Tags: html, xml

I am trying to access data within XML tags, but my code only returns data up until the line break.

Here is my XML code:

```
<job_description>
  App Building
  <BR/>
  More App Building
  <BR/>
  Even More App Building
</job_description>
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
document.write(record[i].getElementsByTagName("job_description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

At the moment, my page only returns the first part of the data in the "job_description" tags, in this case "App Building", but I would like to be able to return all of the data within the "job_description" tags, including what is inside the line breaks. Any suggestions on ways to handle the XML line breaks. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> XHTML documents must use ***lower*** case for all HTML element and attribute names. This difference is necessary because XML is case-sensitive.

See [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/).

Comment: If you are referring to the <BR/> markers, then is there a way to change or remove the XML tags from within my html code? The XML code is automatically being generated, so I need a way to modify it within my html page.